# scraping time travel with R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, nodes, rvest

I need to collect time travelling data from Mappy using web scraping with R.

When a use the following code in R, and i try to read the page so I can extract the time travel, the text that i get does not include the time information.

```
url = GET("https://fr.mappy.com/itineraire#/voiture/Puteaux%2092800/Maisons-Alfort%2094700/car/feuille_de_route/1")

page <- read_html(url)
html_text(page)
```

When I try to extract the information with the nodes like the following i always get character(empty).

```
  a<-read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes("div.C7QTU mainDetail") %>% 
    html_text()
```

I do not know how to only get the time travelling.